# script.readyState is undefined in IE11 & FF

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I just worked on a dynamic script loader which works fine in IE9 but not in IE11 and not in FF.

Here is my code:

```
function getResourceScript(filename)
{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', mShuttlePath + "scripts/" + filename);
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('language', 'javascript');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

function documentLoadInit()
{
    if (document.readyState == 'complete')
    {
        // check if all scripts are loaded
        for (var n = 0; n < document.scripts.length; n++)
        {
            if (document.scripts[n].readyState != "complete" && document.scripts[n].readyState != "loaded")
            {
                setTimeout(documentLoadInit, 49);
                return false;
            }
        }
        Init();
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(documentLoadInit, 49);
    }

}
getResourceScript("core/core.js");
getResourceScript("core/ajax.js");
```

The main problem here is, that the script.readyState is dropped in IE11 - so much I found out!

But how to replace it? How to check When the script is loaded / is finished?

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the `onload` event on the script element.

Comment: At the end, you just want to check if all scripts are loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MSDN:

> Note: For the script element, `readyState` is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use `onload`. For info, see Compatibility changes.

So, instead of checking for the `readyState` you can use something like this:

```
if (!script.addEventListener) {
    //Old IE
    script.attachEvent("onload", function(){
        // script has loaded in IE 7 and 8 as well.
        callBack();
    });
}
else
{
    script.addEventListener("load", function() {
        // Script has loaded.
        callBack();
    });
}
```

Also, I'm pretty sure that you can improve your code. And `setInterval()` is more suitable in this case. Read a little bit about how to use dom events and if you still have compatibility issues, here is something that you could use:

```
function loadExtScript(src, test, callback) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = src;
  document.body.appendChild(s);

  var callbackTimer = setInterval(function() {
    var call = false;
    try {
      call = test.call();
    } catch (e) {}

    if (call) {
      clearInterval(callbackTimer);
      callback.call();
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

The function takes a test as a parameter. Since you are the designer of the app, you’ll know what successful test is. Once this test is true, it will execute the callback.

Comment: +1 @Kovu do not poll for state changes, use events for that. javascript has you covered

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think you're asking if the document is ready before it becomes ready. You need to set up a state change listener and check each time the document state changes.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    initApplication();
  }
}
```

Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState