# IE11 pageload is failing with VBscript

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-11

Need VBScript to work on IE11 page load. readystate is not working on some of the IE pages. I know there is HTML way of get vbscript to work on IE 11 but I am looking for code to work only via vbscript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617535/script-readystate-is-undefined-in-ie11-ff

Comment: thanks for supporting on this with answered questions. Could you please provide the same in vbScript as I am unfamiliar with Jscript.